# How does one make electron-builder copy .pyc files, which are by default excluded?

Tags: python, electron, electron-builder

Because of the [default exclusion rule as shown here](https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents.html#files), electron-builder refuses to copy .pyc files when building. However adding the line

> "files": ["**/*.pyc"]

into the config file doesn't make electron-builder copy the files. It's not obvious how one is expected to achieve this.

The documentation notes that:

> All default ignores are added in any case — you don’t need to repeat it if you configure own patterns.

This would suggest it's impossible to override, and therefore impossible to copy .pyc files. But surely that cannot be right?

Comment: Hi. Are you able to figure something out? If yes, would you mind sharing, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution (worked for Windws 10 at least), with the help of the official document (https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents#extraresources) and after some trial and error.

In `package.json` add a `build/extraResources` section as shown (in the example below, the `python` directory is alongside the `package.json` file, tested with `electron-builder version=23.6.0 os=10.0.19044`):

```
  "build": {
      "asar": false,
      "extraResources": [
        {
          "from": "python/",
          "to": "app/python/",
          "filter": ["**/*.pyc"]
        }
      ]
  }
```

or in `builder-config.yaml` (`electron-builder --win --config builder-config.yaml`) add:

```
asar: false
extraResources:
  - from: python/
    to: app/python/
    filter:
      - '**/*'
```

The `filter` can be futher finetuned (for example `- '**/{foo,bar}.pyc'`).